# Which CCK field properties are shared when using field in different node-types?

Tags: drupal, cck

Which CCK field properties are shared when using a CCK field-type between node-types? I Ask this question because I wanted to re-use a created field 'date' with another node type. When I altered the date notation to input only the year, suddenly I noticed that only the year was showing with the first node-type I set the Date-field to also.

So, what field information is shared between node-types, and what information can be configured per node-type?

Searching the net, I already found Data model-diagrams of the CCK fields module, but they are not detailed enough. The UI of the CCK fields can use this extra bit of information so the user knows what is affected when posting the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on what field type you are dealing with, but the information is already in the UI. Just take a closer look at the fields configuration forms - the 'global' (= used for all field instances) settings are contained in one fieldset, and the instance specific in another. This is noted in the fieldsets descriptions (small print, light gray text in most themes).

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks for the hinge! The problem was I use a custom theme where the styling is not optimal, so it wasn't quite clear. Still, strange that the global settings are not better distinguished from the instance specific settings.